# Robocopy over WINRM

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to use RoboCopy to sync folders on different servers. I don't want to use SMB for security reasons.

I created the following script to try to go through WINRM but it doesn't work.

I'm not sure if Robocopy can be used on anything other than share Drive.

```
 $sesion = New-PSSession -ComputerName SERVERB

Robocopy H:\test \\SERVERB\H:\test2 /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5 /LOG:C:\change.txt

Remove-PSSession -Session $sesion
```

Comment: How about BITS? Powershell remoting is not intended for large-scale file transfers.

Comment: Is just one empty .txt file. The error i get is \\SERVERB\H:\test2\
The network name cannot be found.

Comment: There is no need for a PSSession if You have access to the Server from your computer.

Comment: Yes but to copy the files I need to use share drive and the idea is to use PSSession to make a secure connection and dont have to use share drive

Comment: What, exactly, is the threat model you are trying eliminate with disabling SMB?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't allow you to authenticate to a second machine if you're in a remote session (double hop). So, robocopy won't have permissions to access the remote share you're trying to copy to

There are [ways](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/understanding-and-avoiding-double-hop) around this, just make sure you understand the implications of changing security mechanisms. Personally, I would avoid doing this.

You can also create a PSDrive for the remote share with your credentials and then access the remote server through it's drive letter.

`New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\ServerB\H$\test2" -Credential (Get-Credential)`

---

Also, I think there is an error with some parameters in your command

`Robocopy H:\test \\SERVERB\H:\test2`

Should probably be

`Robocopy H:\test \\SERVERB\H$\test2`

Comment: Yes, I know I have to use $, the thing is I'm trying to avoid using the shared disk for security reasons, because maybe I have to use it in a DMZ